# Jquery translate request from JSON

Tags: jquery, translate

I get an JSON from rest-call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.foe-helper.com/v1/LegendaryBuilding/list', function(alllgs) {
      $.each(alllgs , function(h, is){ 
      $.each(is.buildings, function(hit, ids) {
        
        $('.allegebaeude').append('<option id="lgtops" value="' + ids.id + '" selected="selected" key="' + ids.id + '">' + ids.name + '</option>');
```

```
{"status":200,"response":{"buildings":[{"id":"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4","name":"Observatory"},
```

So I like to translate the ID.
The translationfile ist local stored JSON

```
{"status":200,"response":{"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4":[{"de":"Observatorium"},
```

Is someone out the  who gives me a hint how to solve this? To change the local stored JSON is  no problem for easyer walkthrough.

Comment: if you share the code you use to fetch that data it will be more meaningful answering how to decode that string (lots of people mistaken json for js objects and here isn't clear as well)

Comment: To confirm: you want to convert (translate) from the format in your first snippet to the format in your second snippet?  Or is it only about *translate* as in change the language from "Observatory" to "Observatorium"?

Comment: @freedomn-m I want to translate the Obersavatory to Obervatorium

Comment: Can you change your translation file?  The current format isn't ideal - if you could change the array of translation objects to just an object, it would make the code much simpler.   `"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4":[{"de":"Observatorium"}, {"en":"Observatory"}]` to `"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4": { "de":"Observatorium", "en":"Observatory" }` then your translation is just: `translations["X_AllAge_EasterBonus4"]["de"]` with some minor changes to use variables / the current building id/name

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear to me what you meant when you cited the translationfile.

Anyway as long as you have that json data deserialized in a js object, and given that such an object has a property named `buildings` containing an array of objects each one having the `id` and `name` properties that you wish to map to a new output array that will match `option`s to append to a previously existing select element,

You can proceed like this:

Given the json of the object you are supposed to receive from your api:

```
{"status":200,"response":{"buildings":[{"id":"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4","name":"Observatory"}]}
```

And that the `.buildings` items will map to options with their `id` and `name` property being respectively the value attribute and the content, to be appended inside the previously existing `<select class="allegebaeude">` as you cited here:

```
$('.allegebaeude').append()
```

Here's a demo that defines a static object as what you expected from the api, just perform a `map` on its `buildings` array that will return a set of new `options` and then `.append` the resulting options inside the select:

```js
const data = {
  buildings: [
    {
      "id":"X_AllAge_EasterBonus4",
      "name":"Observatory"
    },
    {
      "id":"SomethingElse",
      "name":"Whatever"
    }
  ]
};

const options = data.buildings.map(item => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', item.id);
  //in your example you attempted to add the attribute key
  //that I replicated here, but it's not meaningful in html per se
  option.setAttribute('key', item.id);
  option.innerText = item.name;
  
  return option;
});

//in your example you selected the select element using a class selector
//such approach might address multiple elements, but I give for granted there's just one
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.allegebaeude');
dropdown.append(...options);
```

```html
<select class="allegebaeude"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the hint I´m looking for